# Proof with multinomial.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, multinomial-coefficients

Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that $p$ divides the multinomial $$\binom {p}{n_1,n_2,\dots, n_k}$$ such that $n_i \neq p$.

I tried some approaches but honestly i have no idea what to do.

Comment: Can you prove that if $a/b$ is an integer, and $p$ divides $a$ but not $b$, then $p$ divides $a/b$?

Answer (score 0):

This follows directly from the formula for the multinomial coefficient:
$$ \binom{p}{n_1 ~ n_2 ~ \cdots ~ n_k} = \frac{p!}{n_1!\,n_2!\cdots n_k!}$$
if you also know that it is always an integer.

(The denominator cannot have $p$ as a prime factor).

Answer (score 0):

We know that 
$$\binom {p}{n_1,n_2,\dots, n_k} = \frac{p!}{n_1!n_2!...n_k!} = \frac{p.(p-1)!}{n_1!n_2!...n_k!} $$

Then it should be clear that 
$$ \frac{\frac{p.(p-1)!}{n_1!n_2!...n_k!}}{p} = \frac{(p-1)!}{n_1!n_2!...n_k!} $$ 
which is an integer(since $p$ doesn't divide the denominator) and you are done.